# please fix the error of trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, if-statement, foreach

Here is the code and it shows "trying to get property 'price' of non-object. Help me fix this please. There is data in $doc and it is not empty.

```
@foreach ($reports as $report)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $report->room_no }}</a>
    </td>
    <td>{{ $report->room_type }}</td>
    @if($report->book_date== null || ($report->book_date != null && ($report->release_date != null && $report->release_date
    < date( 'Y-m-d')))) <td class="text-danger"><strong>Vacant</strong></td>
        <td>{{ $report->price }}</td>
        <td>---</td>
        <td></td>
        @endif

        @if($report->book_date != null && ( $report->release_date ==null || $report->release_date >= date('Y-m-d')))
            @php
                $doc = DB::table('gen_resident_room')->Join('sales_pipeline', 'gen_resident_room.person_id', '=', 'sales_pipeline.id')->where([['room_id',$report->room_id]])->first();
                if(isset($doc->pros_name)){
                    $n = explode (",",$doc->pros_name);
                }
            @endphp
        @if(isset($doc) && isset($doc->stage) && $doc->stage === "MoveIn")
            <td class="text-success"><b>Occupied</b></td>
        @else
            <td class="text-success"><b>Booked</b></td>
        @endif
          <td>{{ $report->price }}</td>
          <td>{{ $doc->price }}</td>
          <td>{{ $n[0] }} {{ $n[1] }} {{ $n[2] }}</td>
        @endif
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Mayur, please include the `error with line number` in your question. Also showing us the response of `$doc` and `$report` will be easy for us to answer your problem.

Comment: i have listed the line where the error is occurring. and also i have checked that $doc and $report isn't empty

Comment: just comment out this line. `<td>{{ $doc->price }}</td>` and check what you get in previous column.is it `Occupied` every time??

Comment: Please include the Error message that you're getting with the output of the line that the is presenting the error. Also try something like `$doc['price']`

Comment: it worked @zahidhasanemon thanx

Answer (score 1):

Use **ternary operator** to check your value is set or not.

```
<td>{{ $report->price ?? '0' }}</td>
<td>{{ $doc->price ?? '0' }}</td>
```

Or you can check `!empty` condition as well.

```
<td>{{ (!empty($report->price) && is_numeric($report->price)) ? $report->price:'0' }}</td>
<td>{{ (!empty($doc->price) && is_numeric($doc->price)) ? $doc->price:'0' }}</td>
```